# Saturation as a VSE Strip Modifier

Tags: modifiers, video-sequence-editor, masking

In the VSE, there's color balance, curves, hue correction, mask and Brightness/contrast as strip modifiers.
But saturation is a normal value of the strip. This makes it impossible to apply saturation via masks.
Is there a plugin that fixes that or a way to add saturation as a modifier or a apply a mask to it some other way?
Kind of annoying. it's not preventing me from achieving anything great or important, but I'm sure it's more pressing to someone!

Answer (score 1):

Use a Hue Correct modifier to the strip, this modifier can use a mask and lets you adjust the hue, saturation and/or value of the strip.

[image: hue correct modifier]

By default the modifier has nine points across the spectrum so you can adjust specific colours, by selecting each internal point and clicking the `X` just above the curve editor you can have two points to get an even adjustment through the hues.

[image: big buck bunny sample]

Comment: Seems needlessly complicated.
I generally find that blender users are accepting too many workarounds and think that that is the reason why the interface is such an unoptimized clusterf***.

Comment: Actually simplifying it is what makes it complex, or at least the wrong thing is simplified. We have one complex modifier that does multiple things and gives full control, instead of multiple simple modifiers that perform one simple thing each. So the modifiers menu is simpler not the modifiers themselves.

Comment: The fewer action one has to take the better. That's the basics of Interface-Design. Having to select and delete all the points is horribly inefficient. In other Software, the points aren't pre-created, they are created as soon as you grab the curve, where you grab the curve. So just grabbing the cure once gives global control.